# Cannot access backend anymore

Tags: magento2, admin, backend, magento-community

I was trying to change my backend URL.
So i changed it in  Stores -> Configuration -> Base URL  To the actual site URL.

Now i am no longer able to access the backend anymore.

All i get is

Whoops, our bad...
The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why.
If you typed the URL directly, please make sure the spelling is correct.
If you clicked on a link to get here, the link is outdated.

Is there any way to fix this?

Comment: Thanks guys, that did it. 
Lesson learned :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to access your database to fix the issue.

**Go to Phpmyadmin**

Go to your database.

Find table `core_config_data`

find field name with **`web/unsecure/base_url`** and **`web/secure/base_url`** and replace value with your own url.

Now Clear Var folder from root.

Check again.

Answer (score 0):

you have to go to database to fix the issue.

**Go to Phpmyadmin**

1)Open your phpmyadmin.

2)Find table `core_config_data`

3)Search for the field name **`web/unsecure/base_url`**

4)Add your URL which is the actual site URL.

Answer (score 0):

Open your Database and click in SQL tab and run this query ::

```
SELECT * FROM `core_config_data` WHERE `path` LIKE '%base_url%'
```

And update your URL